# CSS Grid Border Not Responsive

Tags: css, css-grid

The CSS below works fine on monitor but no border around grid when looking at it on the phone, although the layout is fine the border has gone. Not sure what the issue is.

Looking for container for a list of items - I just thought this would be the best way to go opposed to lists.

I have placed border-box in the @media

```css
    /*-------------GRID------------*/
    
    *,
    *:before,
    *:after {
      box-sizing: border-box;
        border-radius: 25px;
        background-color: dfe1ee;
    }
    
    body {
      margin: 40px;
      background-color: #dfe1ee;
      color: #444;
    }
    
    img {
      max-width: 100%;
    }
    
    h1,
    p {
      margin: 0 0 1em 0;
    }
    
    .media {
      margin-bottom: 2em;
      border: 5px solid #dfe1ee;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    
    .media > .title { grid-area: title; }
    .media > .img { grid-area: img; }
    .media > .content { grid-area: bd; }
    .media > .footer { grid-area: ft; }
    
    .media {
      display: grid;
      grid-column-gap: 20px;
      grid-template-areas:
        "title"
        "img"
        "bd"
        "ft";
    }
    
    
    @media (min-width: 600px) {
    
      /* clearfix*/
      .media:after {
        content: "";
          border: 15px solid #dfe1ee;
        display: block;
        clear: both;
         border-radius: 25px;
        background-color: dfe1ee;
          box-sizing: border-box;
      }
    
      .media > .media {
        margin-left: 160px;
        clear: both;
          border: 5px solid #dfe1ee;
      }
    
      .media .img {
        float: left;
        margin: 0 10px 0 0;
        width: 150px;
      }
      
      .media .footer {
        background-color: #eee;
        padding: 10px;
      }
    
      .media.media-flip .img {
        float: right;
        margin: 0 0 0 10px;
      }
    
      .media > * {
        margin: 0 0 0 160px;
      }
    
      .media.media-flip > * {
        margin: 0 160px 0 0;
      }
    
      @supports(display: grid ) {
        /* override */
        .media > *,
        .media.media-flip > * {
          margin: 0;
        }
        .media .img,
        .media.media-flip .img {
          width: auto;
          margin: 0;
        }
        .media:after {
          content: none;
        }
    
        .media {
          display: grid;
          grid-column-gap: 20px;
          grid-template-columns: 150px 3fr;
          grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
          grid-template-areas:
            "img title"
            "img bd"
            "ft ft";
        }
    
        .media.media-flip {
          grid-template-columns: 3fr 150px ;
          grid-template-areas:
            "title img"
            "bd img"
            "ft ft";
        }
    
        .media.img-flexie {
          grid-template-columns: minmax(150px, 1fr) 3fr;
        }
    
        .media.media-flip.img-flexie {
          grid-template-columns: 3fr minmax(150px, 1fr);
        }
    
        /* nested */
        .media > .media {
          grid-column: 2 / -1 ;
          margin: 0; /* override */
          margin-top: 1em;
        }
      }
    
    
    }
    
    /*-------------GRID------------*/
```

```html
<div class='media'>
  <div class='img'>
    <img src='https://via.placeholder.com/100' width=100>
  </div>
  <div class='content'>
    <p align='right'> STUFF </p>
  </div>
  <div class='footer'> OTHER STUFF </div>
</div>
```

Really need a curved box to outline content.

Comment: Please Post your html code and make it as working snippet,so that  SO community can look into the code which you have tried

Comment: <div class='media'>

  <div class='img'>
   <img src='' width=100>
  </div>
  
 
  <div class='content'>
   
<p align='right'>
STUFF
</p>


  </div>
  <div class='footer'>
    
OTHER STUFF
  </div>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about you, but I see a border on any viewport size?

```css
/*-------------GRID------------*/
    
    *,
    *:before,
    *:after {
      box-sizing: border-box;
     border-radius: 25px;
     background-color: dfe1ee;
    }
    
    body {
      margin: 40px;
      background-color: #dfe1ee;
      color: #444;
    }
    
    img {
      max-width: 100%;
    }
    
    h1,
    p {
      margin: 0 0 1em 0;
    }
    
    .media {
      margin-bottom: 2em;
      border: 5px solid red;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    
    .media > .title { grid-area: title; }
    .media > .img { grid-area: img; }
    .media > .content { grid-area: bd; }
    .media > .footer { grid-area: ft; }
    
    .media {
      display: grid;
      grid-column-gap: 20px;
      grid-template-areas:
        "title"
        "img"
        "bd"
        "ft";
    }
    
    
    @media (min-width: 600px) {
    
      /* clearfix*/
      .media:after {
        content: "";
       border: 15px solid #dfe1ee;
        display: block;
        clear: both;
       border-radius: 25px;
       background-color: dfe1ee;
       box-sizing: border-box;
      }
    
      .media > .media {
        margin-left: 160px;
        clear: both;
       border: 5px solid #dfe1ee;
      }
    
      .media .img {
        float: left;
        margin: 0 10px 0 0;
        width: 150px;
      }
      
      .media .footer {
        background-color: #eee;
        padding: 10px;
      }
    
      .media.media-flip .img {
        float: right;
        margin: 0 0 0 10px;
      }
    
      .media > * {
        margin: 0 0 0 160px;
      }
    
      .media.media-flip > * {
        margin: 0 160px 0 0;
      }
    
      @supports(display: grid ) {
        /* override */
        .media > *,
        .media.media-flip > * {
          margin: 0;
        }
        .media .img,
        .media.media-flip .img {
          width: auto;
          margin: 0;
        }
        .media:after {
          content: none;
        }
    
        .media {
          display: grid;
          grid-column-gap: 20px;
          grid-template-columns: 150px 3fr;
          grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
          grid-template-areas:
            "img title"
            "img bd"
            "ft ft";
        }
    
        .media.media-flip {
          grid-template-columns: 3fr 150px ;
          grid-template-areas:
            "title img"
            "bd img"
            "ft ft";
        }
    
        .media.img-flexie {
          grid-template-columns: minmax(150px, 1fr) 3fr;
        }
    
        .media.media-flip.img-flexie {
          grid-template-columns: 3fr minmax(150px, 1fr);
        }
    
        /* nested */
        .media > .media {
          grid-column: 2 / -1 ;
          margin: 0; /* override */
          margin-top: 1em;
        }
      }
    
    
    }
    
    /*-------------GRID------------*/
```

```html
<div class='media'>
  <div class='img'>
    <img src='https://via.placeholder.com/100' width=100>
  </div>
  <div class='content'>
    <p align='right'> STUFF </p>
  </div>
  <div class='footer'> OTHER STUFF </div>
</div>
```